# Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu keep show when click any things from the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to keep Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu visible when click anywhere in the dropdown menu. But it will be hidden when click on anywhere outside of the dropdown menu.

```
<li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Location <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Bangladesh</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">USA</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by returning false when anything inside the ul is clicked:

```
$(function(){
    $("#open").find("ul").on("click", function(){

        return false;

    }); 
});
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4L7/183/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown" id="open">
    <!-- Dropdown Button -->
    <button id="dLabel" role="button" href="#"
       data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#" 
       class="btn btn-primary">
        Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>

    <!-- Dropdown Menu -->
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" 
        aria-labelledby="dLabel">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZS4L7/182/)

Comment: It doesn't hide when I click out side of the dropdown-menu and it's hide when I select anything from dropdown menu